# Hide a section if there is no data fetched from api call in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am working on data fetched from API call and want to hide the section where there is no data being fetched.Please help with a sample code of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive. This will display the content when the condition is met. You would then need the condition to evaluate to false when the API call is empty, and true when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.http.get<any>("api").subscribe((res:any) => {
    if (!res) {
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.